# Replace part of URL only if doesn't contain a given part

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to replace all URLs containing `31.media.tumblr.com` with `41.media.tumblr.com`. But if URL `31.media.tumblr.com` has `.gif` in it, it must not get changed.

here's my code;, but it changes everything even URLs with `.gif` in them... when I run it:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
    SET post_content 
      = REPLACE(post_content
               ,'31.media.tumblr.com/'
               ,'41.media.tumblr.com/') 
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%' 
      AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif';
```

p.s. here's an example of 31. url with gif at the end

```
https://31.media.tumblr.com/79db8c1df4f893bc20d53063e03834f6/tumblr_n1e93kMh3z1rjbi2lo1_500.gif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That example URL, you provided, is an image, so I suppose that it is inside something like a `<img>` tag, if so.. all you need to do is to add `%` wildcard at the end of `.gif`. That's why the script isn't working, probably.

try this

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'31.media.tumblr.com/','41.media.tumblr.com/')
WHERE post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%' 
AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks fine, I assume the problem is trailing spaces in post_content. Try:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
    SET post_content 
      = REPLACE(post_content
               ,'31.media.tumblr.com/'
               ,'41.media.tumblr.com/') 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%' 
  AND rtrim(post_content) NOT LIKE '%.gif';
```

and see if that helps. Test case:

```
create table wp_posts (post_content varchar(255));
insert into wp_posts 
values ('https://31.media.tumblr.com/79db8c1df4f893bc20d53063e03834f6/tumblr_n1e93kMh3z1rjbi2lo1_500.gif')
insert into wp_posts 
values ('https://31.media.tumblr.com/79db8c1df4f893bc20d53063e03834f6/tumblr_n1e93kMh3z1rjbi2lo1_500.gif ');

select * from wp_posts 
where post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%' 
  AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif';
[...]
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

select * from wp_posts 
where post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%' 
  AND rtrim(post_content) NOT LIKE '%.gif';
[...]
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help. But the other answer actually fixed my problem. i'm going to accept that one!

Comment: Ok, just be aware that an ending wildcard might match more than you wish for. Consider adding the end tag to the pattern.